# Icons Enable command is no longer supported for VSCode >= v1.6.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code does not support **Enable Icon** commend of *vscode-icons* extension after the last update. How can I active the icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete command to enable the icons is called: "Preferences: File Icon Theme". You can fuzzy search for it via the command palette.